# How to navigate the view window to an agent

Tags: java, anylogic

I created a dedicated Agent where I am displaying some diagrams. How exactly do I navigate the view window to display the other agent instead of the main agent?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "ViewArea" object. Place it into your agent so it includes the charts.

Given that your agents are embedded into Main, you can view each individual agent by using the code "myAgents.get(0).myViewArea.navigateTo()" <-- this will show you the first agent in the population myAgents...

Also, refer to more help in my : [blog post on view areas](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/3/28/anylogic-user-interface-vol-4-the-view-area)

Hope this helps to get you started

Comment: It doesn't work. "Description: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field". Since it's just a single agent type I used `Visualization2D.viewArea.navigateTo()`

Comment: You need to understand how to navigate through your model, that "Visualization2D" is not needed at any point. Check the ANyLogic help for the page "Where am I and how do I get to" to understand how to call objects from any place in your model

Comment: "Visualization2D" is the name of the agent type I want to navigate to and is not a population and not embedded anywhere.

Comment: If its not even embedded in Main, how did you instantiate it at all? Does it even exist at runtime? You cannot navigate to an Agent-type, only to instantiated agents. Agent-types are like Java classes. They only exist as objects when you instantiate them!